# Proving $\sup_n\mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^2]}\le \left( \sup_n\mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^p]}\right)^{2/p}$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value, supremum-and-infimum

Can everyone help me prove the following inequality??
$$\sup_n\mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^2]}\le \left( \sup_n\mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^p]}\right)^{2/p}, $$
with $\{X_n\}$ is a centered independent sequence and $p>2$.

Applying Holder inequality I obtain that $\mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^2]}\le \left( \mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^p]}\right)^{2/p}$. How can I continue to solve this problem??

Comment: Applying Holder inequality I obtain that $\mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^2]}\le \left( \mathbb{E} {[|X_n|^p]}\right)^{2/p}$. How can I continue to solve this problem??

Comment: Thus, for every $n$, $$\mathbb{E}[|X_n|^2]\leqslant\mathbb{E} [|X_n|^p]^{2/p}\leqslant\sup_k\mathbb{E} [|X_k|^p]^{2/p}=\left(\sup_k\mathbb{E}[|X_k|^p]\right)^{2/p}.$$ Now consider the supremum over $n$ of the LHS.

Comment: @Did Why $\sup_k\mathbb{E} [|X_k|^p]^{2/p}=\left(\sup_k\mathbb{E}[|X_k|^p]\right)^{2/p}$? Where can I research this properties? Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply note that, for every nonnegative family $(x_k)$ and every continuous increasing function $u$, one has $\sup\limits_k u(x_k)=u\left(\sup\limits_k x_k\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a_n\geq0$, $\alpha >0$, $(\sup_na_n)^\alpha=\sup_{n}a_n^\alpha$, so we only need to prove
$$(E|X_n|^2)^p\leq (E|X_n|^p)^2$$
for all $n$. By applying Jensen's inequality with the convex function $\phi(.)=|.|^{p/2}$,
$$(E|X_n|^2)^p= \Big(\big(E|X_n|^2\big)^{p/2}\Big)^2\leq E\Big((|X_n|^2)^{p/2}\Big)^2=(E|X_n|^p)^2.$$